# date_format PHP error DateTimeInterface

Tags: php, html, date

estoy intentando darle un formato a una variable para almacenarla de la siguiente forma "Martes, 23 de Julio de 2019" para esto tengo un *input* el cual es formato Date:

```
<input autocomplete="off" value="<?php  echo date("Y-m-d")?>"name="fecha_ingreso" type="date" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2">
```

esta variable la envió al controlador y luego al modelo, donde intento darle el formato de la siguiente forma:

```
 $fecha_ingeso = $this->input->post('fecha_ingreso');
 $fecha2 = date_format($fecha_ingeso, 'l \,');
```

para por ultimo hacer el Insert en la base de datos.
pero me da el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

`date_format()`, es una variante del método `format` de la clase `DateTime`. Eso quiere decir que necesita un objeto `DateTime` para trabajar.

Puedes hacerlo así, usando además la función propia de la clase, y no su sucedánea:

```
#Creamos un objeto DateTime a partir de $fecha_ingreso
$fecha2 = new DateTime($fecha_ingeso);
#Creamos un formato personalizado, el que esparas, según planteas en la pregunta
$customFormat='l\, d \d\e F \d\e Y';
#Formateamos en base a ese formato
echo $fecha2->format($customFormat);
```

Comment: muchas gracias fue de ayuda pero como ultimo detalle me interesa guardar la variable en un varchar como puedo pasar la variable a string? probé con un par de métodos "strval" y (string) pero me da error y el campo de la base de datos queda en blanco.

Comment: @NicolasRudisky si es para una base de datos no te aconsejo que la guardes formateada. El formato es algo relativo, puedes necesitar representar una fecha de mil maneras y no conviene guardarla mil veces, **es mejor guardarla en formato `YYYYMMDD` en una columna del tipo `DATETIME`** y luego en el contexto en que la necesites la formateas. No sé si me entiendes lo que quiero decirte. Es un grave error guardar una fecha formateada en la BD. Además, cuando haya que hacer cálculos con la fecha, etc, te vas a complicar la vida.

Comment: si te entiendo la variable la guardo 2 veces normal y formateada ya que la utilizo varias veces.

Comment: @NicolasRudisky No tienes que guardarla dos veces, ni en PHP ni en la base de datos, ten cuidado con eso, sobre todo en la base de datos, pues estarías incurriendo en algo que se llama *redundancia de datos* (tener datos repetidos sin necesidad). Y en PHP, una vez creado el objeto, puedes usar `format` para representarlo como quieras, de mil formas o de diez mil formas. El formato es algo relativo como ya dije, por eso un formato se crea de forma dinámica y se presenta allí donde se necesita, **no tiene ningún sentido guardar datos formateados**.